# Где можно найти готовые layout-ы для Android приложения?

Tags: android, android-layout, ui, material-design

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть ли готовые Layout-ы, свои больно смотреть,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю готовых нету, но я могу ошибаться. По поводу - `свои больно смотреть`: это нормально что ваш дизайн выглядит мягко говоря не очень, но на то вы и программист а не дизайнер, чтобы делать так чтобы вью элементы работали, а уже дизайнер должен думать над тем как это нарисовать. Я могу вам предложить несколько вариантов:

1. Забить - самый простой :)
2. Пытаться изменить самостоятельно - это довольно сложно, если у вас нет виденья общей картинки. Для этого вам придется гуглить тонны информации, смотреть туториалы и тд. чтобы в итоге то что вы переделаете вам  не понравится и вы вернетесь к п. 1.
3. Найти хорошего (вероятнее всего дорогого) дизайнера и заказать у него дизайн вашего приложения.
4. Найти среднего-плохого дизайнера (дешево, но сердито) - это позволит вам причесать немного ваше творение, но плохой дизайнер как вы понимаете конфетку из вашего приложения не сделает.

[Вот](https://material.io/design/) гайдлайны material design от Google может пригодится. Но хочу вас предостеречь, что если вы все-таки выберете п.1 то есть вероятность что ваше приложение не будет воспринято должным образом. То что вы беспокоитесь над дизайном это нормально, но не нужно фанатизма :) У вас все получится, Удачи :)